# VB.NET Custom DataGridView control - Duplicate columns at runtime?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I am making a control that inherits from DataGridView.  I am adding columns programmaticly in the controls constructor, like so.

```vb
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()

'This call is required by the Component Designer.
InitializeComponent()

OptionsForm = New frmOptions(Me)

'NOTE: Add columns programmatically rather than via the designers properties window, or they will be duplicated when added to a form!
Dim colIpAddress, colPort, colStatus, colSpeed, colCountry As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    colIpAddress.HeaderText = "IP"
    colPort.HeaderText = "Port"
    colStatus.HeaderText = "Status"
    colSpeed.HeaderText = "Speed"
    colCountry.HeaderText = "Country"

    Columns.AddRange({colIpAddress, colPort, colStatus, colSpeed, colCountry})

    RowCount = 1
Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

When I add the control to a form, it displays the columns correctly.  But during runtime, the columns are duplicated.  I added a if statement so that the columns would only be added if the current column count was 0, still to no avail.

Anyone know whats going on?  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property on your `DataGridView` control to false:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this myself by adding a check before adding the columns, and only adding them if it's in design mode.  I think I understand why this was occurring now.

```vb
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()

'This call is required by the Component Designer.
InitializeComponent()

If Me.DesignMode Then
    OptionsForm = New frmOptions(Me)
    AutoGenerateColumns = False
    'NOTE: Add columns programmatically rather than via the designers properties window, or they will be duplicated when added to a form!
    Dim colIpAddress, colPort, colStatus, colSpeed, colCountry As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    colIpAddress.HeaderText = "IP"
    colPort.HeaderText = "Port"
    colStatus.HeaderText = "Status"
    colSpeed.HeaderText = "Speed"
    colCountry.HeaderText = "Country"

    Columns.AddRange({colIpAddress, colPort, colStatus, colSpeed, colCountry})

    RowCount = 1
    Me.Refresh()
End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps someone when `AutoGenerateColumns = False` isn't working.

Comment: _AutoGenerateColumns = False isn't working_ - I am doubt about this, but it difficult to be sure without information about how data was added to the `DataGridView`

Comment: It's in virtual mode, adding via CellValueNeeded.  Not setting the DataSource.